# How to strip a string from a datetime stamp?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, row, datetime-format, strip

I am reading the attached excel file (only an image attached) using Pandas. There is one row with DateTime stamp with following format (M- 05.02.2018 13:41:51). I would like to separate/remove the 'M-' from DateTime in the whole row.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df=df.drop([0,1,2,3])
```

I would then like to use the following code to convert to Datetime:

```
df.iloc[0]= pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Can please someone help me to remove the 'M-' from the complete row?

Thank you.

[Excel-file (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phDwN.jpg)

Comment: How about slicing the df.iloc[0] to df.iloc[0][2:] ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove `'M-'` from the rows:

If removing from the `rows`:

```
df['Column_Name'] = df['Column_Name'].str.strip('M- ')
```

If removing from `columns` or `DataFrame headers`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('M- ')
```

Comment: It was an idea how you can use, it depends on how you read the data into dataframe, you might need to make some changes once you read the data. Since the solution from other answer worked for you, you should use that, else please let me know I can make changes to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want [`Series.str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html#pandas.Series.str.lstrip) to remove leading characters from row.

```py
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].str.lstrip('M- ')
```

Comment: df.iloc[:,0] indicates first column rather than row. I've tried with df.iloc[0] and it worked. :)

Comment: @JuttSb I have edited answer as you say. if it's worked for you please [accept or up vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer.